# Can you be disciplined for 'intention' to cheat but didn't?

Tags: exams

I have an grad sch exam where I can bring in a single textbook of choice for reference. I borrowed one from the sch library and find that multiple books have evidence of previous students writing notes. I am ashamed to admit that I considered doing it too, just as a fail-safe as I have studied very hard for this but its still a hard module so I'm still worried. And the only reason why I 'woke up' from it is that I was talking about it in a public train with a friend not from this course, and realized that someone could have overheard me and report it to my uni. I'm paranoid about being overheard and reported because it was very obvious that I had the intention to consider it at least. I know its bad that that was the reason that I 'woke up' from but I have reflected on my train of thought leading to my decision to consider it, which a very small part of me is grateful for because I did not realize how big my anxiety about doing well for this had snowballed into.

Answer (score 3):

You can relax - nobody is going to try to initiate disciplinary measures over a snippet of conversation overheard on a train. We all occasionally think about doing things we know we shouldn't, so you don't need to feel guilty for thinking about it - you didn't do it, after all.

What kind of "notes" are being written in the textbooks? Unless these are answers to exam or homework questions, I can't fathom why anyone would care that students were writing in the textbooks, and if they ARE answers to exam/homework questions, you could consider bringing it to your professors' attention that answers to their homeworks and exams are floating around out there.

In general, an academic institution is only going to take action if they actually think that you cheated. They may take evidence of "intention" to cheat as reason to open such an investigation, but if there's no actual evidence someone cheated they're likely to drop it.

Comment: True, I just live in a very small country/community that anyone could have easily find me by searching my uni n the title of the book I was holding so I kind of got paranoid if I just happened to meet a really angry person. We have access to limited past year papers by uni so you can kind of predict the pattern of questions lol.

Comment: You really can relax about this, and it is not as big a deal as you're worried about. This would require someone on the train to 1) notice you conversation, 2) know what textbook you're using, 3) lookup your university based on that textbook, and finally 4) go to the trouble of reporting it to the institution. There is no chance anyone on the train cared enough to do all that. There is also very little chance that anyone in the university is interested in opening an investigation based on "well, I heard one of your students talking about how there was writing in their textbook on the train."

Comment: Alright, thanks you make sense and I'm bring sort of overly worried about it. Also I realized that the rules technically did not say you can't write in it but that you can't bring other printed material.